# How to fix ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError on Angular mat-expansion-panel

Tags: angular, angular-material

Objective: If user clicks any **top** level mat-expansion-panel-header element then collapse any open **nested** level mat-expansion-panel-header elements, eg:

1. Click *Main heading 1* to expand it
2. Click *Subheading 1* to expand it
3. Click *Main heading 1* to collapse it. This should fire an event that collapses *Subheading 1*.

This is essentially a 'housekeeping' task to clean up if user leaves panels expanded.

Issue: If you double click one of the **top** level mat-expansion-panel-header elements in quick succession (eg: whilst the expand/collapse animations are still running), the following error is thrown in the console:

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'mat-expanded: false'. Current value: 'mat-expanded: true'.

If you continue to fire these errors, eventually it keeps firing indefinitely and the browser completely locks up.

See Stackblitz project here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/expression-changed-error

I was considering doing something like disabling clicks until the open/close animation has finished, but I'm sure there must be a reason that this is happening and a proper fix for it.

Comment: your stackblitz demo is running fine there is no error

Comment: error occurs only on double click.

Comment: Yes, only occurs if you double click quickly (whilst expand/collapse animations are still running)

Answer (score 4):

Please remove the following code from html to resolve the error.

```
(afterExpand)="collapseSub(panel)"
```

From collapseSub function I see that you are trying to close the panels and open only the selected one. 
**But this is already handled by default.**
You are trying to change the expanded state of panel when it is already handled by default;

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want to remove `(afterExpand)="collapseSub(panel)"`, then you can try this solution.

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

collapseSub = (panel: MatExpansionPanel) => {
    const items = this.matExpansionPanelQueryList.filter(item => item.expanded === true);
    if (items) {
      items.forEach(item => {
        item.close();
      });
    }
    panel.open();
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

`this.cdRef.detectChanges();` adding this line will do the trick for you.

Comment: No it won't work completely because there's a bug using changeDetectorRef. https://stackblitz.com/edit/expression-changed-error-smcy4q

Comment: @ng-suhas you are right. it first it leaves some space between two expansion panels and then again on click it show the content and hide automatically.

Comment: Yes indeed. I think the solution provided by Narayanan looks fine.

Comment: yes i tried Narryanan solution and it works perfect. but i think usage of `(afterExpand)=` was that he want to close the chid expansion after opening the parent expansion. because by default child expansion panel will remain in same state after expand  and collapse of parent.

Comment: @FarhatZaman That's absolutely right; that is what I am trying to do. I have updated the original question which will hopefully provide some clarity.

Answer (score 1):

The simple fix is to schedule your changes after the end of the current event cycle using `setTimeout`:

```
collapseSub = (panel: MatExpansionPanel) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const items = this.matExpansionPanelQueryList.filter(item => item.expanded === true);
    if (items) {
      items.forEach(item => {
        item.close();
      });
    }
    panel.open();
  });
}
```